# copying specific files with shutil()

Tags: python, shutil

I have a folder with 7500 images. I need to copy the first 600 images to a new folder using the shutil module in Python.

I tried to look for relevant stuff on the net but the usage of the paths is a bit confusing. What exactly should be my sequence of commands? I guess it will start like:

```
import os
import shutil
l=os.listdir(path)
for file in l[0:600]:
```

Edit: after having clarification on what `shutil.copy()` does, I came up with:

```
import os
import shutil
l=os.listdir(path)
for file in l[0:600]:
    shutil.copy(file, destination, *, follow_symlinks = True)
```

But it's highlighting the comma after *, and giving the error `iterable argument unpacking follows keyword argument unpacking`. What's going wrong in the syntax?

Comment: what counts as the first 600? i.e. how are you sorting them?

Comment: they are named as 0000, 0001,0002....jpg

Comment: Files don't have a defined order in directories, so you would have to do something like sort them by name to give them one (otherwise the order is random). You're get the error in your edit because of the `*` — why did you stick that in there as it makes no sense.

Comment: remove the *,. they are for arguments you are not using

Answer (score 0):

Well, `os.listdir()` will return files randomly sorted, one thing you could do is that you can call `os.stat(file).st_mtime` on each file which will return timestamp when that file was last modified and then you can sort the files by that time to get first/last files. But it really depends on your use-case and how you interpret what first files are for you. But when it comes to shutil library you can just call:

```
for file in l[0:600]:
    shutil.copy(file, f'./destination/{file}')
```

which will copy 600 files into directory that is in your current directory and named 'destination'.

Comment: can you provide the exact syntax of shutil.copy()?

Comment: jsut remove * from your code you provided in edit

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir(path)` will list files and sub direcotries in your directory you're searching.

I'm making the assumption that all you're files will be `.jpg` so I would use the `glob` module.

```py
import glob
path = "D:Pictures\*.jpg"
destination = r"E:\new_pictures\\"
files = glob.glob(path)

for f in sorted(files)[:600]:
    shutil.copy(f, destination)
```